# C++ argument pack recursion with two arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a template class that uses two types:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2> class Foo { ... };
```

I need to write a function that takes any number of `Foo` variables:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Others> size_t getSize(Foo<T1,T2> *f, Foo<Others>*... o) { ... };
```

If I implement the `class Foo` with only one template parameter, it works well.
But with two (or more) parameters, the compiler complains that `Foo<Others>` requires two args.

Is is possible to achieve argument pack forwarding when the `class Foo` has multiple template parameters ?

Comment: Basically you must have an even number of parameters in the pack, and they have to be used to deduce the function parameters. This is probably directly doable with C++20 concepts (have to think about it), but with C++17 and earlier it will be necessary to use several indirections, and perhaps some helper classes and functions. Now what ***exactly*** do you intend to do with the template parameters, in the function itself? Is this deduction even needed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is a duplicate - I should have the other question saved in a bookmark. Will be back in an hour to mark it, if that's the case.

Comment: No, it should not be `Foo<Others...>`, because `Foo` has exactly two template parameters.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. twice.

Comment: It might be possible to avoid recursion (e.g. if all you want to do is iterate over parameters). If possible, you should do that.

Comment: What is the target here? Is it `getSize( Foo<A,B>*, Foo<C,D>*, Foo<E,F>*) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
template <typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
std::size_t get_size (Foo<Ts1, Ts2> * ... fs)
 { /* ... */ }
```

?

Or, maybe,

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Us1, typename ... Us2>
std::size_t get_size (Foo<T1, T2> * f, Foo<Us1, Us2> * ... fs)
 { /* ... */ }
```

if you want a first `Foo` managed differently.

Comment: Works ! Did not be aware that you can use multiple arg packs.

Comment: @dexter - newer underestimate the power of the dar... ehm... I mean... the perversion of the variadic templates.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is `Foo<Others>*... o` argument.
Unpacking that argument for a template pack `A, B, C, D, E` would yield you with as many `o` arguments: `Foo<A>, Foo<B>, Foo<C>, ...`.

In my opinion, it would be simpler if you just declare your arguments as `Other` and let the recursion fail if they won't match with any `Foo` instantiation later on:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Others> size_t getSize(Foo<T1,T2> *f, Others... *o) { ... };
```

Here, each `Others` type in the pack will be deduced to the type you pass. If you call `getSize` recursively with a reduced number of arguments, they will all eventually be matched with a `Foo<T1,T2>` argument:

```
return f->size() 
     + getSize(std::forward<Others>(o)...); // the first argument in the pack will
                                            // be Foo<T3,T4> type 
                                            // or the compilation will fail
```

You could also add a type trait to do the check directly:

```
template <class T> struct IsFoo : std::false_type {};
template <class T, class U> struct IsFoo<Foo<T,U>> : std::true_type {};

template </* ... */>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction<IsFoo<Others>::value...>::value, size_t> getSize(/* ... */)
```